# Input tag - How to hide a specific value in input text

Tags: jsp, input

I wish to have a specific value to be hidden in the auto populate field without deleting it in the database.

For example, I don't want the word "apple" to come up on the auto populate.

Is it possible to add condition in the input syntax?

This is my current code:

```
<input type="text" id="fruitsSearch" style="width: 60%" />
```

I tried adding hidden and value tag but stilll unsuccessful.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you talking about [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete)?

Comment: Hello. Thanks but I've seen this awhile ago.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I didn't ask if you've seen it, I asked to confirm that's what you're talking about when you say "auto populate".

Comment: I've tried the hidden and select.

Comment: Hi Amadan. Yes it is.

Comment: I mean add some codes that you tried.

Comment: Codes are now available. Thanks

Comment: Then apart from the settings for the `autocorrect` attribute listed in that page, there is nothing else to be done. As an alternative, you can use [`<datalist>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist) or implement your own autocomplete, so you can completely control the source of the autocomplete rather than rely on browser's input history.